# What state is a AWS snapshot at after completed

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an instance that keeps running, and I create a snapshot at time A,
After 4 hours, the snapshot creation completed, However during this 4 hour interval, a lot of change has occurred (imagine i keep downloading data). So, what is the actual state of the snapshot? Is it the same as the machine at time A ? or Is it the same as the machine at time A + 4 hour? A or A+4h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good comprehensive answer from Roid. The short version is that the snapshot always reflects the state **at the time it's started**, ie in your point A. Subsequent changes on the filesystem don't affect the snapshot in progress.

Note that without a reboot the filesystem may be in an inconsistent state - without all the OS buffers flushed to the disks. The safest is to tick the reboot option when taking a snapshot / creating an AMI image.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Got you! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

From official [Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html)

> You can back up the data on your Amazon EBS volumes to Amazon S3 by
> taking point-in-time snapshots. Snapshots are incremental backups,
> which means that only the blocks on the device that have changed after
> your most recent snapshot are saved. This minimizes the time required
> to create the snapshot and saves on storage costs by not duplicating
> data. Each snapshot contains all of the information that is needed to
> restore your data (from the moment when the snapshot was taken) to a
> new EBS volume.

---

**Relations among multiple snapshots of the same volume**

The diagram in this section shows how incremental snapshots can be taken from different volumes.

[image]

Comment: The key part here is "point in time snapshots". The snapshot is consistent with what is written to EBS at the time the snapshot is started. It could be that there is data in RAM that needs to be flushed to disk, but my experience is snapshots usually work ok. If you want really consistent snapshots you'd have to shut down your applications and work out how to flush RAM to disk - turning the instance off is the easy but highly disruptive way.